# Pbrun not allowing to execute commands

Tags: command

Why do I get this when I execute `pbrun`.

```
$ pbrun ls
You are NOT allowed to use pbrun -h <remotehost> ls.
Please try again without -h option.

Host: xxxx
Submithost: xxxx.abcd.xyz.com


pbrun7.5.0-12[404]: Request rejected by pbmasterd on server1234.abcd.yyyy.com.
```

I am actually trying to execute printer related commands like `lpshut`, `lpadmin`, etc with `pbrun`.
But it throws the exact error as above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a name resolution issue between the submithost you are running pbrun and the Masterhost.

For the variable "clienthost", pbrun first gets the hostname, (i.e. hostname command), pbrun then gets the ipaddress of the hostname returned and then finally, pbrun then reverse resolves the ipaddress on the submithost and populates the "clienthost" variable with this result. (forward and reverse name resolution is important)

The variable "host" will be the same as "clienthost" if -h is not used with pbrun.

The variable "host" is the value passed to pbrun with the -h switch. If the value of runhost is not explicitly set in the policy, its value comes from host.

Submithost is the reverse resolved hostname on the masterhost based on the ipaddress that is taken from the source ipaddress in the IP packet header.

On the submithost, host is being set to the short name as that is returned by the getent system call for its IP.

On the Masterhost, submithost is being set to the FQDN as that is returned by the getent system call for the source IP of the submithost.

Part of this is because the submithost is resolving via files, /etc/hosts has the short name as the canonical name, and the masterhost is doing DNS resolution returning the FQDN.

Addressing this is either via name resolution changes, or policy changes.
Name resolution could be editing the /etc/hosts file on the submithost to have the canonical name as FQDN.
Policy changes can be either setting the runhost to the submit host, so both are the same, or which might be better, when doing hostname comparisons, you can do a short name comparison.

Somewhere in your policy you have something like:

```
if (submithost != runhost) {

  print{"You are NOT allowed to use pbrun -h <remotehost> ls."};

  print{"Please try again without -h option.\n\n"};

  print{"Host:", host};

  print{"Submithost:", submithost};

  reject;

}
```

You will want to change your condition to something like:

```
if (split(submithost,".")[0] != split(runhost,".")[0]) {
```

This will do an explicit shortname hostname comparison.
If you already have a function that does this, or are using the pblibs.conf sample policy, there is a defined function for this.

```
#

#   The function GetShortName will take a host name and return the

# short name of the FQDN, or just return the shortname if the

# the short name was passed as the argument. This function requires

# one argument, a string for the hostname.

# To call the function:

# GetShortName("test.beyondtrust.com");

# GetShortName(masterhost);

#

function GetShortName(SomeHostName) {

  GetShortName = split(SomeHostName,".")[0];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
pbrun -h "machine name"
```

or

```
pbrun -h "machine name" pbksh
```

Comment: Why does this work? This is a 2 year old question, has this been a bug that was fixed? Or was `-h` the correct thing to use back then?